# Dotnet core add bower and static files

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I've just created a new dotnet core project with the following:

```
dotnet new webapi
```

The created the following folders and files:

 bin 
controllers 
obj 
wwwroot (empty) 
dotnet.csproj 
Program.cs 
Startup.cs

Now i want to get started with bower (bootstrap, jQuery, angular 1.x) and add static files to my project. But this should be added in wwwroot folder with lib, images, js and css, right? How do i add this to my current project?

I've checked the following link to add static files, but gives me an error:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#serving-default-files

```
the type or namespace name 'StaticFiles' does not exist in the name space 'Microsoft.AspNetCore'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: install node with npm then install bower if you require it. now you can create a bower json file in the wwwroot folder and just `bower install` it.

Comment: @Jai Gives me the following error:
bower ENOENT        No bower.json present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install bower globally on your system: `npm install -g bower`

Create `.bowerrc` file in the root of your application with the following content, this tells bower where to restore files:

```
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

Initialise bower by running `bower init`, this will create a `bower.json` file in the root of you application. You can now start install vendor packages by running a command like the following - nb. you can search for packages at https://bower.io/search/:

`bower install jquery --save`

To start serving static files from your dotnetcore application run the following:

`dotnet add package Microsoft.AspnetCore.StaticFiles`

Then in your Startup.cs add the line `app.UseStaticFiles();` before the line `app.UseMvc();`

Restore, build, run and you should be able to access your static files in a url like http://localhost:5000/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Static Files dependency in your project.json file

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0"
```

Comment: where is that file located, because i can't find it

Comment: `project.json` file should be on your root directory, btw which code editor you are using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code, not sure if that's the problem.

Seems like i have to add it to dotnet.csproj with the following:

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.0.0" />

Now i doesn't give me an error with StaticFiles, but with PhysicalFileProvider, Path and PathString. Do i need to add more packages for these?

Comment: csproj ? which version of dotnet cli you are using, I am using `1.0.0-preview2-003133`. I think you have the latest version [Read this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-tools-msbuild-alpha/)

Comment: You are correct. I am using version 1.1 something. Thanks for the link!

Comment: btw, you don't need to add any reference for `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders`

Comment: It just gives me the error: 

The type or namespace name 'PhysicalFileProvider' could not be found.

EDIT:

Adding this works:

using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;